# Parsing FIX messages for further analytics

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm currently trying to parse my FIX messages to get 2 columns showing currency (tag55) and price (tag133) but having difficulty using 'awk' as it appears the desired part of the message isn't split into columns (in bold for your reference).  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

```
FIX log example:
03:55:16.128 incoming           20180528-07:55:16.015           8587130         11891           8587030         S                  **8=FIX.4.29=013535=S49=IUAT2Feed56=FixServer50=IUAT2Feed_Offers34=858713052=20180528-07:55:16.015117=055=NOK/SEK7225=7133=1.0735135=2100000010=159**
03:55:16.128 incoming           20180528-07:55:16.015           8587131         11891           8587030         S                  **8=FIX.4.29=013435=S49=IUAT2Feed56=FixServer50=IUAT2Feed_Offers34=858713152=20180528-07:55:16.015117=055=USD/CNH7225=2133=6.3872135=300000010=110**
```

Desired output:

```
NOK/SEK 1.0735
USD/CNH 6.3872
```

Comment: `awk -F'=' '{gsub(/7225/,""); print $11, $13}' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
  perl -F= -pale '$_ = sprintf "%.7s %.4f", @F[-5,-3]'   fix.log
```

¶  how it works :

```
 °  split each line as it comes on equal to sign. Store the split values in the array @F

 °  counting from the end of the array @F, the last but 4th  and last but 2nd fields are what we need.

 °  we require the 7 chars and accuracy upto 4 digits.

 °  stuff these in $_ and -p option auto prints it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk -F"=" '{sub(/[0-9]+/,"",$(NF-4));print $(NF-4),$(NF-2)+0}' OFMT="%.05g"  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do:

```
$ awk -F= '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ "NOK" || $i ~ "USD"){print $i,$(i+2)}}' input_file | awk '{gsub(/[0-9]/,"",$1)}1'
NOK/SEK 1.0735135
USD/CNH 6.3872135
```